# Unable to plot multiple data sets in GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm using GUIDE to display a plot within an axis that contains two data sets: the original signal and the average of the signal, but for some reason it seems to only plot one.

The axis is designated as `m_graph` and the data sets are `avg` and `signal`, which both share `time`.

```
plot(handles.m_graph, time,signal)
hold on
plot(handles.m_graph, time, avg)
```

When I compile the program, only the average is plotted. It seems to skip over the original signal or reset the axis. I've tried plotting just the signal so I know the data is fine.

I feel like I am missing something, maybe the `set` function?

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much

Comment: The solution was hold(handles.m_graph,'on')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my reasoning was a bit wrong; it applies to the current selected axes (it does not parent to the Figure).

However, using `axes(h)` followed by `hold on` or just `hold(h,'on')` will either switch the focus to the axes then turn hold on or turn hold on for a specified axes, respectively.